# python уменьшить колво запрос к бд

Tags: python, sql, база-данных

models

```
class Album(models.Model):
    pass


class Photo(models.Model):
    album = fk(album)
```

view

```
albums_ = Album.objects.all()
print("count db: ", len(db.connection.queries))
for album_ in albums_:
    a = album_.photo_set.all()
    print("for cycle stage 1: ", len(db.connection.queries))
    stadium_.fields_count = len(a)
    print("for cycle stage 2: ", len(db.connection.queries))
```

*мне нужно добавить количество фото в одном альбоме но используя len или count количетсво запросов к базе увеличивается по итерации подскажите пожалуйста правильный подход или возможно лучшую практику без применения цикла*

Comment: Сделать альбому IntegerField и хранить в нём количество

Comment: количество может меняться создать get_ в моделях, выйдет тоже самое как я понимаю неужели нету хорошего решения

Comment: Очевидно, с изменением количества нужно будет обновлять и этот IntegerField. Денормализация базы данных с целью уменьшения числа запросов — это и есть хорошее решение, которое все везде делают

Comment: понял спасибо действительно. но все же почему при простом подсчете len() создается новый запрос?

Comment: А как это без запроса-то сделать